# SpringBoot test cannot Autowire service when profile is use

Tags: spring-boot-test

I was trying to run SpringBoot test for my command liner application by the following below

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-junit-prevent-runner-beans-testing-execution

It is working if I do not have Autowried in the Test class

if I use the Autowired annoatation with ActiveProfiles annatation, it fails to load the service component class.

Can someone please give me a hint how to address it?

Answer (score 0):

For a get around, we can check the active profile before executing the main process

```
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        if (!Stream.of(env.getActiveProfiles()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)).contains("test")) {
            myMainProcess();
        }

    }
```